# All connections in pool are in use

Tags: c#, sql, database, sql-server-2008, database-connection

We currently have a little situation on our hands - it seems that someone, somewhere forgot to close the connection in code. Result is that the pool of connections is relatively quickly exhausted. As a temporary patch we added `Max Pool Size = 500;` to our connection string on web service, and recycle pool when all connections are spent, until we figure this out.

So far we have done this:

```
SELECT SPId
FROM MASTER..SysProcesses
WHERE DBId = DB_ID('MyDb')  and last_batch < DATEADD(MINUTE, -15, GETDATE())
```

to get SPID's that aren't used for 15 minutes. We're now trying to get the query that was executed last using that SPID with:

```
DBCC INPUTBUFFER(61)
```

but the queries displayed are various, meaning either something on base level regarding connection manipulation was broken, or our deduction is erroneous...

Is there an error in our thinking here? Does the DBCC / sysprocesses give results we're expecting or is there some side-effect catch? (for example, connections in pool influence?)

(please, stick to what we could find out using SQL since the guys that did the code are many and not all present right now)

Comment: `the guys that did the code are many and not all present right now` .. I don't think they were all there when they forgot to close their SQL Connections. ;)

Comment: you have the source code right? It shouldn't be hard to look for all the connection opens and close them, provided they aren't deliberately passing connections around...

Comment: @will @mitch - you *don't* want to look at the code, trust me :) but, eventually, that was the only option at the end... and we fixed it by putting try-finally{close} everywhere...

Comment: You could tidy up the try-finally{close} with a "using" construct.  This will call the Dispose method on the connection which should close it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would expect that there is a myriad of different queries 'remembered' by inputbuffer - depending on the timing of your failure and the variety of queries you run, it seems unlikely that you'd see consistent queries in this way. Recall that the connections will eventually be closed, but only when they're GC'd and finalized.

As Mitch suggests, you need to scour your source for connection-opens and ensure they're localized and wrapped in a using(). Also look for possibly-long-lived objects that might be holding on to connections. In an early version of our catalog ASP page objects held connections that weren't managed properly.

To narrow it down, can you monitor connection-counts (perfmon) as you focus on specific portions of your app? Does it happen more in CRUD areas vs. reporting or other queries? That might help narrow down the source-scour you need to do.

Comment: After frantically going through code and putting everywhere the `try - finally { conn.Close() }` we managed to save the issue...the design of the anti-pattern controller class was (**is**) a horror... there'll be spanking in the morning that's for sure ;) thanks everyone...

Comment: @Mitch: If it's .NET's DB connection the finalizer will call dispose which will free up the unmanaged resources. It just happens at an indeterminate time becuase of GC timing.

Comment: @veljkoz: You probably know this, but you can save some typing by wrapping your connections in using() blocks which effectively do the try/finally for you.

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to change the connection strings to contain information about where and why the connection was created in the Application field?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? Could you give an example?

Comment: You can provide an "Application Name" property of up 128 characters which is displayed in SQL - this can make debugging rogue connections much easier (in each unique location in the app where the connection is created use a different name).  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring.aspx.